# custom widget with child widgets kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to do self.add_widget() inside a custom widget? I have a very large python file that I want to split up. In doing so, what I have is my main window which has several different widgets, moved into a separate class. Originally I had this widget fill up using a loop and add_widget() using the id in the .kv file. I moved it out and it should return a single GridLayout that gets placed into the .kv file.

EDIT:
I made a small mistake in my explanation, its not a custom widget like `class custom(Widget):` its a custom GridLayout `class custom(GridLayout):`

And inside a function I have `self.add_widget(Button())`. When ran I get the error: `AttributeError: 'custom' object has no attribute '_trigger_layout'`

Answer (score 1):

When do you want to add and what do you want to add are the questions actually...

If you have a custom widget(that inherits from Widget or some other widgets), you can call `self.add_widget(arg)` in init or in function. Make yourself a keyword where you pass a widget and you can use it like this `Custom(what=Button())` where you catch `what` like this:

```
class Custom(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Custom, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.add_widget(kw['what'])
```

To use it in function, save `what` in class variable(`self.<var>`) and use it later in `self.add_widget(self.<var>)`